# Facebook App Notifcations PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I've been reading through the facebook developer docs and i'm a little confused, I want to re-engage a load of users that have gone a little stale really by giving them a little nudge regarding their inactivity on our app...

What is the current "best practice/latest way" of doing this, it seems to be via the notifications API?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/#imp

If i'm correct can someone give me a couple of pointers for a PHP implementation of this, essentially it would be a cron running once a month/every two weeks wizzing through users who haven't logged in for a while and prodding them.

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since nobody responded to this heres a simple working solution that I figured out from the docs. To notify a user they have to authorised your app.

```
$book = new Facebook((array(
'appId'  => 'XXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
'grant_type' => 'client_credentials')
 ));

$vars = array(
"access_token" => $book->getAppId().'|'.$book->getApiSecret(),
"href" => "index.php", 
"template" => "Some text to send up to 180 characters",
"ref" => "This is what shows up in insights so you can track responses"
);

$post = $book->api('/' . $userid . '/notifications/', 'post', $vars);
```

You can insert user names into template by surrounding the facebook user id with {} ie:
"{12345} would like to play some game with you." . It will throw an exception though if the uid refers to a user that hasn't authed your app.

Href automatically gets your canvas url inserted infront of it so no need to full domain/path.

ref is used in the insights interface so you can see which notifications are generating traffic!

Thats it, very simple to re-engage those users who seem to have disappeared!

Cheers

Marc