# What variables are there available in the Facebook Notification API Templating?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, notifications

Scrolling through Facebooks App Notification section of the API, you will find details about the templating at the very bottom, [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications#templating)

`@[USER_ID]` is mentioned, which is converted into the recipients full name. Are there other such dynamic inputs available when sending notifications? If there are, such inputs would be very useful for me and potentially anyone using the API. I've had a look around and can't find any information about this. It wouldn't be the first time undocumented functionality exists in the Facebook API, however.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look, and also found no documentation on this. But given the verbose syntax, i would suspect not much else is supported.

But supposedly it *is* possible to insert username (not to confused with person full name!) by using `{12345}` in your message, *if* this user *authed* your app. Thats according to this  [Facebook App Notifcations PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289057/facebook-app-notifcations-php) question.

I'm afraid that is all i can point out, besides experimenting with more `;:.~+!#$%^&*@[]{}()` bracket combinations. I would expect notifications have template insert mechanisms for the App name, its organization name, and perhaps even for the number of unread notifications. Whether these are exposed to API users, i wouldn't know..

Comment: Appreciate the information and second opinion. Hopefully someone will find what we might have missed.. dynamic templating would be extremely useful!

Comment: As per the doc, It only replaces the user's full name and auto highlight along with your message. Other then replacing the full name there is no templating option available at this moment.